# sorting algorithm to keep sort position numbers updated

Tags: algorithm, sorting, language-agnostic, position

Every once in a while I must deal with a list of elements that the user can sort manually.

In most cases I try to rely on a model using an order sensitive container, however this is not always possible and resort to adding a position field to my data. This position field is a double type, therefore I can always calculate a position between two numbers. However this is not ideal, because I am concerned about reaching an edge case where I do not have enough numerical precision to continue inserting between two numbers.

I am having doubts about the best approach to maintain my position numbers. The first thought is traversing all the rows and give them a round number after every insertion, like:

Right after dropping a row between 2 and 3:

```
1   2   2.5   3   4    5
```

After position numbers update:

```
1   2   3     4   5    6
```

That of course, might get heavy if I have a high number of entries. Not specially in memory, but to store all new values back to the disk/database. I usually work with some type of ORM and mobile software. Updating all the codes will pull out of disk every object and will set them as dirty, leading to a re-verification of all the related validation rules of my data model.

I could also wait until the precision is not enough to calculate a number between two positions. However the user experience would be bad, since the same operation will no longer require the same amount of time.

I believe that there is an standard algorithm for these cases that regularly and consistently keep the position numbers updated, or **just some of them**. Ideally it should be O(log n), with no big time differences between the worst and best cases.

Being honest I also think that anything that must be user/sorted, cannot grow as large as to become a real problem in its worst case. The edge case seems also to be extremely rare, even more if I search a solution pushing the *border numbers*. However I still believe that there is an standard well known solution for this problem which I am not aware of, and I would like to learn about it.

Comment: Is it practical for your case to put the elements in a mutable-array/array-list/vector?

Comment: no, it is not practical. Any change must be immediately saved back to disk without knowing how it is saved.

Comment: If there was a type of float with unlimited numerical precision. would it satisfy?

Comment: yes. that would do. The root of this problem is not being able to calculate "and store" a position between two float numbers an infinite number of times.

Comment: If you keep a number as a string instead of as a float, and you come up with a procedure that can take two such numbers and return the middle number. Will it help?

Comment: sounds as a possible solution, however the sole idea of using such approach makes me feel... "dirty", fear that I might not sleep at night thinking about the meaning of my life because I have resorted to such decivious tricks, fear that one day I could wake up sweating in my bed because of nightmares resulting from the algorithmic crimes I committed in my foolish youth. Using strings would increase the storage and sorting to unreasonable costs, not in the sense of availability, but in the practical-4-this-problem sense. I coded my heuristics based solution, my grail is its algorithmic version

Comment: I believe you! Can you allow a maintenance period? if so then you can use your original solution with the heavy work, the 'relaxing' stage, then.

Answer (score 4):

Second try.

Consider the full range of `position` values, say 0 -> 1000

The first item we insert should have a position of 500. Our list is now :

```
(0) -> 500 -> (1000).
```

If you insert another item at first position, we end up with :

```
(0) -> 250 -> 500 -> (1000).
```

If we keep inserting items at first position, we gonna have a problem, as our ranges are not equally balanced and... Wait... *balanced* ? Doesn't it sounds like a [binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) problem !?

Basically, you store your list as a binary tree. When inserting a node, you assign it a position according to surrounding nodes. When your tree become unbalanced, you rotate nodes to make it balanced again and you recompute position for rotated nodes !

So :

- Most of the time, adding a node will not require to change position of other nodes.
- When balancing is required, only a subset of your items will be changed.
- It's *O(log n)* !

**EDIT**

[image: algorithm explained]

Comment: I think we need some more details about how this works. Suppose that there are *n* items in the list and you have assigned them the numbers *k* to *kn* where *k* = maxint // *n* (or some other perfectly balanced scheme). Then the user moves the last item to the beginning. How does your algorithm rebalance the numerical assignment?

Comment: There are some problems with your proposal. Binary trees are not naturally balanced, maybe you are thinking about an AVL tree. This problem deals with consecutive nodes, hence a B style tree could be an advantage. You also mention "store your list as a binary tree", however a database is my backend, an ORM maps that to memory, and my data model digest that. I would love not to leak my design until the storage level. I would prefer doing something within my model class. I thought about temporally reverse building a B+ tree (and avoid B* compaction) that pushes away edge nodes... not good yet :(

Comment: @Nicolas: You don't need to explain how [self-balancing binary trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree) work in general. But how does your proposal work in the particular case I described in my comment? (The point being that a self-balancing binary tree balances the *height of the tree*, whereas in this problem we need to balance the *distribution of numbers across the range*, and it's not clear that balancing the one also balances the other.)

Comment: wow! just saw your recent edit. I understood how you want to rebalance the ranges, but I am still concerned about how you want to "contain" the rebalanced position values within only one section (and avoid the propagation of modifications). More like: I have [0,8,10,11,50] and want to insert between 10 and 11. Use 10.5? Push 10? Better to push 11 to 50/2 since it has more room (and just one contained level push)

Comment: @GarethRees certainly the guy worked for his answer and he got one upvote from me because of his work. But I believe it is still not a good solution. Look at my previous comment example. It seems to point into a direction where the container is not important, easy to implement, but maybe it is not the right approach. Certainly it seems promising since it can grow upwards as more edge position numbers are pushed away.

Comment: @GarethRees: as each node split its assigned range in two equals parts and in turn assign these parts to its two sub nodes, we can safely say that if we keep the tree height balanced, we keep the distribution of `position`s across the available range balanced too. That's the whole point of this!

Comment: @Nicolas: I agree that given a balanced tree, we can compute a balanced distribution of numbers. But I'm not yet convinced that every  *update* to a balanced tree only results in O(log *n*) reassignments. If a node changes depth (as it might after a [rotation](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/43/BinaryTreeRotations.svg)) it may have only half the available range it had before the change of depth: correcting this might require reassigning the numbers to most of its descendants. In particular, your last step ("reapply ranges") looks like it's O(*n*).

Answer (score 0):

If the user is actually sorting the list manually, then is there really any need to worry about taking O(*n*) to record the new order? It's O(*n*) in any case just to display the list to the user.

Comment: Thanks Gareth, I was just updating my question about how heavy an O(n) can be. However I already did mention that the worst case seems unlikely to happen, therefore my biggest concern is my curiosity about finding an algorithm for a problem that seems quite common.

Answer (score 0):

This not really answers the question but...

As you talked about "adding a position field to your data", I suppose that your data store is a relational database and that your data has some kind of identifier.

So maybe you can implement a [doubly linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list) by adding a `previous_data_id` and `next_data_id` to your data. Insert/move/remove operations thus are *O(1)*.

Loading such a collection from a database is rather easy:

- Fetch each item and add them to a map with their id as key.
- For each item connect it with its previous and next item.
- Starting with the first item (`previous_data_id` is undefined) follow the chain and add them to a list.

Comment: I was about to post an answer, but yours essentially gives the same solution - a double linked list combined with a Dictionary/HashMap where the values are nodes in the list. Moving an item should be O(1) since getting the node is an O(1) operation, and deleting and reinserting the node in the list is O(1). The data structure would be very similar to what is commonly used to implement an LRU cache, but put to a different purpose.

Comment: I do not think that using or not a relational database will change the problem that much. If the user can sort manually, this user input must be stored, no matter if it is SQL or NoSQL. Of course, I could benefit of some NoSQL storage having sorted containers. However in the second paragraph, I immediately mention that I am looking for a solution for those cases when I do not have a sorted container. On one side I want to avoid the extra layer remapping my data to an intermediate structure. On the other I am just interested in the algorithmic challenge of exactly this problem.

Answer (score 0):

After some days with no valid answer. This is my theory:

The real challenge here is a practical solution. Maybe there is a mathematical correct solution, but every day that goes by, it seems that the implementation would be of a great complexity. A good solution should not only be mathematically correct, but also balanced with the nature the problem, the low chances to meet it, and its minor implications. Like how useless it could be killing flies with bullets, although extremely effective.

I am starting to believe that a good answer could be: to the hell with the right solution, leave it like one line calculation and live with the rare case where sorting of two elements might fail. It is not worth to increase complexity and invest time or money in such nity-picky problem, so rare, that causes no data damage, just a temporal UX glitch.